# I downloaded a file with uTorrent and now I can't find it

Tags: files, downloads, utorrent

I installed uTorrent using the Ubuntu Software Center. I downloaded a huge file using uTorrent and now I can't find it. It says the file is in a path that doesn't exist in my computer, and I don't know how to find it. I'm pretty new using Linux...

Comment: For what it's worth I would advise against using uTorrent as it has had some problems in the past with security, malware and ethical choices by it's developers - although the current developers may not be responsible for that. Try Transmission instead which is available in the Ubuntu Software center too.

Comment: Thanks @KristopherIves ! I'll try with Transmission next time :) 

I still woud appreciate if someone knows how to find where the file is because I spent about 30 hours downloading it (haha I don't have a good internet service)

Comment: have you mounted a drive on a directory above it, thus it's hidden/shadowed? It wasn't a 'live' system (uninstalled) or saved to a tmpfs (temporary file-system which exists in memory only)

Comment: I couldn't find it as a hidden file but I'll check what you are saying... Thank you very much!

Comment: When you `mount /dev/device /dir` it mounts the device onto the /dir directory; and any files/directories that were in the /dir directory are shadowed (hidden) by the new `mount`, and will remain that way safely until you `umount /dir` or remove the shadow & they re-appear. I was not talking about +hid fs-flags, or .filenames , but possible `mount` (or user-done things) as a possible cause..

Answer (score 2):

If the file exists and is in a mounted partition you should be able to find it with `find`.

It helps if you know the name or part of the name, for example you know that `ubuntu` is part of the name and you know that it is an iso file. You can sort the iso files according to time with the newest files last,

```
sudo find / -iname "*ubuntu*.iso" -printf "%T+ %p\n"|sort
```

or if don't know anything about the name but you know that the download was done within the two last days (modify if necessary), and that it is *not* a hidden file or in a hidden directory inside your home directory.

```
sudo find ~/* /media -type f -mtime -2 -printf "%T+ %p\n"|sort
```

You can put a size limit too, for example 500 MiB, and then you need not drown in hidden configuration files (there was only one that big file for me, a thunderbird imap inbox file),

```
sudo find ~ /media -type f -size +500M -mtime -2 -printf "%T+ %p\n"|sort
```

Answer (score 2):

In your file browser, make sure the "Show hidden files" (Ctrl+H) is enabled. Follow the path

```
Downloads/snap/uTorrent/common/.wine/drive_c/users/home_directory/Downloads/
```

There you go, and the downloaded uTorrent file is right before you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find files by opening the file browser and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>